# Implementing pointers and arrays ported to Java

Tags: java, c++, pointers

I am porting some C++ code over to Java that uses some heavy pointer arithmetic. 
My problem is the following:

There is a structure built as such that I have implemented as a class:

In the original C/C++ code I have the following assignments,

```
struct mst_edge
{
    int u, v;
    double w;
}

mst_edge * tree_edges = new mst_edge[size];

int node_l = tree_edges->u;
int node_r = tree_edges->v;
```

How is it possible to convert this code to java? The second block declares `mst_edge` as a C/C++ dynamic array. But in the third block of code it uses the tree_edges as a direct pointer.

What would the Java equivalent of this be, considering memory and references are handled directly by Java?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the reference to the first value of the array?

Comment: The `<code>` tags can only be used for code that doesn't contain newlines. See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for more info.

Comment: The second block **defines** `tree_edges` as a pointer to `mst_edge` and initializes it with an array allocated on the free store. It is emphatically not a C dynamic array; C doesn't have `new`.

Answer (score 1):

The Java equivalent is

```
mst_edge[] tree_edges = new mst_edge[size];

int node_l = tree_edges[0].u;
int node_r = tree_edges[0].v;
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct in C/C++ is like a class in Java with all its member variables `public`:

```
class MstEdge
{
    public int u;
    public int v;
    public double w;
}
```

You wouldn't normally do that in Java; the member variables would be `private`, with `public` accessor methods, but that's closest to a `struct`.

A pointer to an array in C/C++ is just an array in Java.

```
MstEdge[] treeEdges = new MstEdge[size];
```

But take care, in Java, declaring an array means now you have `size` `null` elements.  Initialize them like this:

```
treeEdges[0] = new MstEdge();  // and so on for other array positions
```

Instead of treating a pointer as a direct reference to the first element as in C/C++, in Java you must explicitly refer to the first element.

```
int nodeL = treeEdges[0].u;
int nodeR = treeEdges[0].v;
```

Answer (score 0):

In OO Java you would use getters to retrieve the private member variables. size is whatever value you have defined.

```
class MstEdge {
    private int u;
    private int v;
    private double w;

    public int getU() {
        return u;
    }

    public int getV() {
        return v;
    }
   .
   .
   .
}


MstEdge [] treeEdges = new MstEdge[size];

int nodeL = treeEdges[i].getU();
int nodeR = treeEdges[i].getV();
```

Comment: Ok. All of your answers are the same as what I came up with....so the error I am encountering (in the overall runtime) must be related to something else...hmmm